# How to do a stacked bar chart with specific values for X axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, stacked-chart

I have been looking into many tutorials about this without success so far. 
I have this simple dataset.

```
TestCases     Column-1  Column-2 
TestCase-1        2       5     
TestCase-2        3       8
TestCase-3        4       7
TestCase-4        5       9
TestCase-5        2       7
```

I need to make, in ggplot, a stacked histogram combining the values of Column-1 and Column-2 and having in the X axis the names of the TestCases column, e.g, TestCase-1, TestCase2, etc.

Comment: Perhaps part of the problem you're having is that what you're describing is not a histogram, but a bar chart.

Comment: I think you mean a stacked bar chart since you are looking at discrete values. see `barplot` in base R or something like `geom_bar` in `ggplot2`.

Comment: Yes, indeed is a stacked bar chart, I have seen geom_bar in ggplot but not getting any result so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape your data first with `tidyr::gather`, then you can plot with `ggplot`.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
  TestCases     Column-1  Column-2 
  TestCase-1        2       5     
  TestCase-2        3       8
  TestCase-3        4       7
  TestCase-4        5       9
  TestCase-5        2       7")

df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, key = "Column", value = "Values", -TestCases)
ggplot(df2, aes(x = TestCases, y = Values, fill = Column)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Identity")
```

Comment: I still would like to know how to convert my CSV data, which I read from R to the text containing the data, as you posted. But, it worked!! Thanks a lot!